# VS Code: run RLS on all .rs files

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo, rust-language-server

I have a Cargo package that I have opened as a workspace in Visual Studio Code. This way, the source code in `.rs` files in type checked through the Rust Language Server. But it only catches the files which are dependencies of `main.rs` where the `main` function is. It does not do type checking when I edit a new `newfile.rs` file, so trivial errors like this, are not caught by VS Code:
`let a: int = "hi!";`

However, if I include this section in `Cargo.toml`, then the source code is handled by RLS:

```
[[bin]]
name = "foo"
path = "src/newfile.rs"
```

**Is it possible to add something to `Cargo.toml` such that all `.rs` files are handled by RLS?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible because that is how rust code is resolved. Rust code can only be valid under a crate context with a certain module-wise path. The compilation of a mod also depends on how the `mod` is defined (accessibility modifier and attributes/macros attached to the `mod`).